# Experience Cloud Announcement Section

Tags: community-builder, experience-cloud

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_announcement.htm&type=5

While going through the document it says we have an Announcement Section in the Experience Cloud, but I never found one in Builder site.

Can you please let me know if there is any access I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you choose Help center template? Look at this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_component_reference_table.htm&type=5

In Build your Own (Aura) I can see it.

[image: Announcement section]

Edit: And be sure to check Show all components!
[image: Show all components]

Comment: Yep, it sounds like OP just isn't using a template that supports the component.

Comment: That might be true. I don't see "Group Engagement" and "Groups" in the Components

Comment: but I can see the Template is "Customer Service"

Comment: Be sure to check Show All Components in Experience Builder > Settings > Advanced > Show all components

Comment: Original answer edited to include the picture

Comment: @RubénCastaños I think this Announcement component is specific to certain group.
Is there a way we can show this Announcement Section to public too?